# Border in shape XML

Tags: android, android-layout, border, shapes, stroke

I am trying to make a drawable to use for a button. I would like it to have this coloring, with a 2px border around it.

Everything works just fine except I cannot get the border to show up...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient android:startColor="@color/bar_clicked_dark"
        android:endColor="@color/bar_clicked_light"
        android:angle="90"/>

    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp" />

    <stroke android:width="2dp" 
        color="#ff00ffff" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 326, accepted):

It looks like you forgot the prefix on the color attribute. Try

```
 <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff00ffff"/>
```

Answer (score 95):

If you want make a border in a shape xml. You need to use:

For the external border,you need to use:

```
<stroke/>
```

For the internal background,you need to use:

```
<solid/>
```

If you want to set corners,you need to use:

```
<corners/>
```

If you want a padding betwen border and the internal elements,you need to use:

```
<padding/>
```

Here is a shape xml example using the above items. It works for me

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
  <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#D0CFCC" /> 
  <solid android:color="#F8F7F5" /> 
  <corners android:radius="10dp" />
  <padding android:left="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: and how to make "U" shape using this type of xml drawable?

Answer (score 11):

We can add drawable .xml like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">


    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/color_C4CDD5"/>

    <corners android:radius="8dp"/>

    <solid
        android:color="@color/color_white"/>

</shape>
```