# Custom View with animation,color and border containing inner textview

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

Referring to below image, I want that view with yellow background and right border to slide in from right with some text. So this requirements include:

- creating a custom view (which will need canvas I guess)
- giving it width, height, position, color, border, border-color, etc.
- animation to slide from right
- textview within this custom view to display text

I referred [this](http://android-er.blogspot.nl/2011/08/drawpath-on-canvas.html) tutorial to understand how to include view with a canvas in layout. But instead of hard coded point positions, I tried following:

```
public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) DashBoardActivity.mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        width = size.x;
        height = size.y;

        width -= 10;
        height -= 50;
        myPath = new Pt[6];
        myPath[0] = new Pt(width, height);
        myPath[1] = new Pt(width - 400, height);
        myPath[2] = new Pt(width - 500, height - 100);
        myPath[3] = new Pt(width - 400, height - 200);
        myPath[4] = new Pt(width, height - 200);
        myPath[5] = new Pt(width, height);
}
```

But view is not getting positioned as per the expectation. I tried with different hard-coded positions, but either it's getting displayed at wrong position or not getting displayed at all.

Also, to show the text, I added textview in the layout itself but it is getting displayed at top left of the screen instead of the position shown in below image.

How I can achieve this ? Any suggestions appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need any custom view for this, you can set shape or 9patch image as background to the textview and animate that textview using object animator.
[Border in shape xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698927/border-in-shape-xml)

Comment: If it would been normal shape i.e. Rectangle, Circle, etc. then this would been fine. But how can I implement polygon?